# Batch Script to find out whether a host is up or down

Tags: windows-7, batch

I need to scan several systems in the network within IP range 172.18.x.x to 172.25.x.x and check whether each of them is active or not, and then dump the result in a file. Following is the script:

```
@echo off
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    ping -n 1 172.%%x.%%y.%%z | find "Reply" > NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (set state=UP) ELSE (set state=DOWN)

    echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is %state% >> state.txt
)))
```

But, the result concludes that every system is 'UP' even though some IP addresses are unused.

Any problem with the script?

Comment: Why use a script ? Why not use one of the many solutions that are out there already ?

Comment: The root cause behind this is the following-
http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/tool-or-script-for-collecting-network-inventory

Comment: i suppose it would be a problem with the script.. if it is saying an IP is up when it is not.  You write "But, the result concludes that every system is 'UP' even though some IP addresses are unused."   can you state an IP it says is up that doesn't exist?

Comment: IP addresses in the range 172.22.x.x to 172.24.x.x are existing, rest are not.
But the result displays "172.18.1.1 is UP", "172.18.1.2 is UP" and so on.

Comment: Since you are a linux man, You may love a program called Cygwin for Window http://www.cygwin.com/  s. It has a load of linux commands for windows. Also gnuwin32 http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html  download coreutils and others.

Comment: Right. But, my target is to collect network inventory information of all the systems deployed across our infrastructure. Above script is only the portion of the tentative original script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in your script was a very weird thing about batch scripts. To get environment variables to update within an IF or FOR you have to use `setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`  and  `!var!`. If you are curious,  the absurdity (what happens if you don't include that setlocal line with the !var!) is explained further in `set /?`.

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    ping -n 1 172.%%x.%%y.%%z | find "Reply" > NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (set state=UP) ELSE (set state=DOWN)

    echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is !state! >> state.txt
)))
```

And if you only want the ones that are up. Try this

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /L %%x in (18,1,25) do (
    for /L %%y in (1,1,254) do (
        for /L %%z in (1,1,254) do (

    ping -n 1 -w 1000 172.%%x.%%y.%%z | find "Reply" > NUL
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        set state=UP
        echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is !state! >> state.txt
    ) ELSE (
        set state=DOWN
    )
)))
```

Comment: Shall I replace "Reply" with "TTL"?
It is creating problem when the result is-"Reply from x.x.x.x: Destination Host is Unreachable"

Comment: @MandarShinde yeah makes sense

Comment: @MandarShinde you could do -w 1000 too  so it doesn't try for more than a second

Comment: Now, issue with "TTL" as following error occurs - Reply from x.x.x.x: TTL expired in transit.

Comment: @MandarShinde  do `| find "TTL="`

Comment: @MandarShinde I suppose you could even replace the whole IF, removing the state variable. Using this-   `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 echo 172.%%x.%%y.%%z is UP >> state.txt`  and then you could remove the setlocal line too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com/free-software-inventory-audit-tool/)(I am suggesting this after viewing your question https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6993/tool-or-script-for-collecting-network-inventory ). All the details you needed is available with spiceworks inventry tool.It is best fit for Windows AD, but it can be done in the either way also.

Comment: I tried that too (but a trial version) and believe me, it took more than half an hour for scanning 8 nodes providing their IP addresses and Host names only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many systems you have to check.. Found a solution right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408673/how-to-ping-multiple-servers-and-return-ip-address-and-hostnames-using-batch-scr).. If you find it easy to do like this, accept this answer...

```
For /f %%i in (testservers.txt) do ping -n 1 %%i >>state.txt
```

**include all ip's in testservers.txt

Comment: There are about 15,000-20,000 systems. So, including IP address of each and every system in a file manually will not be feasible, I guess.

Comment: Why do you need a batch script?? Can't you use any third party application for this ??

Comment: I need to collect network inventory details of all the systems deployed across our infrastructure. I am planning to do this using scripts. With this portion of script, I can get IP addresses of all active machines in the network.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tool like [Angry IP Scanner](http://angryip.org/about/) to do this job. Scripting it seems pointless when there are so many other tools out there that can do the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence.
Actually, I need to collect network inventory details of all the systems deployed across our infrastructure. I am planning to do this using scripts. With this portion of script, I can get IP addresses of all active machines in the network.

Comment: What details do you need from your systems ? What OS are they running ?

Comment: IP Address, MAC Address, Host Name, Make Model, User Details, Processor & OS.
95% of the systems are running Windows (XP, Vista or Win 7) and others are running Linux (RHEL or SLES). We can ignore Linux systems, as of now.

Comment: I'd do it in Powershell rather than Batch script then.